# struts2 FilterDispatcher not found

Tags: struts2

I am new to struts2 and trying to build the example described in this tutorial https://www.tutorialspoint.com/struts_2/index.htm I am pretty sure to have followed the example correctly but I always get this error when trying to start the application:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher
at ...
```

looking in the net, I see it is a very common error and got a lot of workarounds but no one worked for me. Otherwise, can you point me to a struts2 tutorial with working examples?

Comment: Also tried org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter since I use struts 2.5 but does not work, it generates a lots of error in tomcat ...

Comment: I have solved upgrading tomcat from 7.0 to 8.0.